# FirstOrDefault(Of Time) when I really want "FirstOrNothing" vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

In linq, I am trying to return a date based off a set of criteria or, if there is no value I want to return `Nothing`.  `FirstOrDefault()` returns the default date if the value is null (1-1-0001 12:00:00AM), which means a `.HasValue` on it will return true.

If I use `First()`, it throws a `System.NotSupportedException` and recommends that I use `FirstOrDefault()` instead.

```
.Property = table.LinkedTableName.Where(Function(r) r.statusId = desiredStatusId) _
.Select(Function(r) r.Date) _
.OrderBy(Function(r) table.Date).FirstOrDefault()
```

This is all within a `Select New DataObject() With {}`

I have found a [custom extension](http://extensionmethod.net/vb/ienumerable-t/firstornothing) on it:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function FirstOrNothing(Of T As Structure)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), _
 match As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As Nullable(Of T)
    For Each item In source
        If match(item) Then
            Return item
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I am interested to know if there are any built in methods or easier ways to handle this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Select your `DateTime` as a nullable `DateTime`, then the default value will be null, which is what that custom extension method does at the tail end. There is nothing built in but you can express it in your projection instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `DateTime` is a value type and can not be `nothing` `FirstOrDefault` can not return `nothing`. You can however cast it to a nullable `DateTime` before you do `FirstOrDefault`

```
(Function(r) Directcast(table.Date, DateTime?)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: My `DateTime` property is a Nullable Property, does this change?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` used on a nullable field will return `Nothing` when the sequence is empty.

Comment: You can verify this by writing: `Enumerable.Range(0, 0).[Select](Function(e) DirectCast(DateTime.Now, System.Nullable(Of DateTime))).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Interesting.  It is definitely a nullable and definitely returning the default value.  Perhaps because the field it is selecting is a `DateTime2` and the property it was being enterted to was `As Date?`   How would this affect it, why would `Nothing` not be returned?

Comment: Are you sure the sequence is empty?

Comment: Yes.  Just checked my data set.  Later, when I filter the results, if I do 
`If item.NullableDateTime = New DateTime(1,1,1)` it evaluates to true.